# How to Write a Comparator to Generalize two types of Objects in Java?

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I used the following method call to return a List of Objects.

```
final List<LinkModelSpi> documentLinks = this.documentLinksModelSpi.getDocumentLinks();
```

Next I used a `Comparator` to sort this list. But List contain Two types of object. Some functionally works it Return ***DocumentLinkModelImpl*** and some function operations it return ***LinkModelImpl***.So , Comparator function passed Class Cast exception when *LinkModelImple* change to *DocumentLinkModelImpl* .This both object parent type also deference.

```
// Add This method for Sorting Document Link View Same Order. Now The application display same links order
// in catalogue administration edit drug window
Collections.sort(documentLinks,
    (Comparator<? super LinkModelSpi>) new Comparator<DocumentLinkModelImpl>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(DocumentLinkModelImpl o1, DocumentLinkModelImpl o2) {
        return o1.getResource().compareTo(o2.getResource());
      }

      /*@Override
      public int compare(LinkModelImpl o1,LinkModelImpl o2) {
        return o1.getResource().compareTo(o2.getResource());
      }*/

});
```

I need some expert help to resolve the matter?

Note: 
I added above sort method newly, but before I added it, the method executed well for all objects.

```
final List<LinkModelSpi> documentLinks = this.documentLinksModelSpi.getDocumentLinks();

for (final LinkModelSpi documentLinkModelSpi : documentLinks)
{
  //noinspection unchecked
  ((DtoPresentationModelSpi<?, MDTO>) documentLinkModelSpi).addPropertyChangeListener(this);
}
```

--------------ERROR----------------------

```
Presentation.impl.LinkModelImpl cannot be cast to Presentation.impl.DocumentLinkModelImpl
    at Client.catadmin.view.component.AbstractEditLinkDialog$1.compare(AbstractEditLinkDialog.java:171)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)
```

Comment: Your `DocumentLinkModelImpl` is a subtype of `LinkModelSpi` and looking at the code that you commented out, the `getResource` function is available on `LinkModelSpi` -- so why don't you make a comparator for `LinkModelSpi` only? It will work for *any* subtype of `LinkModelSpi` including `DocumentLinkModelImpl`.

Comment: But sir it passed error. I will add error to question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me be clearer what I mean with my comment. If both `DocumentLinkModelImpl` and `LinkModelImpl` have a method `getResource`, then chances are that the supertype (can't see if it's an interface implemented by both or a superclass) `LinkModelSpi` has a method `getResource` as well. So then you can just write:

```
Collections.sort(documentLinks,
    new Comparator<LinkModelSpi>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(LinkModelSpi o1, LinkModelSpi o2) {
        return o1.getResource().compareTo(o2.getResource());
      }
});
```

Even if that's not the case, you can work it out:

```
Collections.sort(documentLinks,
    new Comparator<LinkModelSpi>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(LinkModelSpi o1, LinkModelSpi o2) {
        String resource1, resource2; // String or whatever type the getResource method returns
        if (o1 instanceof DocumentLinkModelImpl) {
            resource1 = ((DocumentLinkModelImpl)o1).getResource();
        } else if (o1 instanceof LinkModelImpl) {
            resource1 = ((LinkModelImpl)o1).getResource();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if (o2 instanceof DocumentLinkModelImpl) {
            resource2 = ((DocumentLinkModelImpl)o2).getResource();
        } else if (o2 instanceof LinkModelImpl) {
            resource2 = ((LinkModelImpl)o2).getResource();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return resource1.compareTo(resource2);
      }
});
```

(of course you'd factor the `instanceof` checking into its own method to clean up that code)

Comment: thank you sir, the matter is, LinkModelSpi has not a method getResource ...!!!I think it is not implanted same super class.Your second solution I will be try.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve above trouble adding this code fragment. But I need to know some , more Advanced solution , if know any one.

```
if (Checks.checkNotNullAndNonEmpty(documentLinks)) {
  if (this.documentLinksModelSpi.getDocumentLinks().iterator().next() instanceof DocumentLinkModelSpi) {

  } else {

  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good and robust solution to me. What is it lacking? I mean, why and how do you need anything more advanced that this solution is not giving you?

Comment: I like to know , are there any generalize way to write comparator function , Can be pass , two object like this. (e.g: using java Generics )